# How to use regular expression in sed command

Tags: regex, sed

i have some strings with this pattern in some files:

- domain.com/page-10
- domain.com/page-15
  ....

and i want to replace them with something like

- domain.com/apple-10.html
- domain.com/apple-15.html

i have found that i can use sed command to replace them at a time but because after the numbers should something be added i guess i have to use regular expression to do it. but i don't know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bash
sed -i.bak -r 's/page-([0-9]+)/apple-\1.html/' file

sed  's/page-\([0-9][0-9]*\)/apple-\1.html/' file > t && mv t file
```

Besides sed, you can also use gawk's `gensub()`

```bash
awk '{b=gensub(/page-([0-9]+)/,"apple-\\1.html","g",$0) ;print b  }' file
```

Comment: You didn't see the entirety of what the OP wants.

Comment: Uses a GNU Sed extension - can be written in standard sed replacing the '+' with '[0-9]*'.

Comment: @jonathan, you sure? `*` is zero or more. `+` is one or more. `[0-9] [0-9]*` should be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, so when the '+' is replaced as I said, then you end up with '[0-9][0-9]*' which is one or more digits - and, as you said, that is appropriate (and I agree).

Answer (score 6):

```bash
sed -i 's/page-\([0-9]*\)/apple-\1.html/' <filename>
```

The `([0-9]*)` *captures* a group of digits; the `\1` in the replacement string references that capture and adds it as part of the replacement string.

You may want to use something like `-i.backup` if you need to keep a copy of the file without the replacements, or just omit the -i and instead use the I/O redirection method instead.

Comment: You didn't specify how to use \d+

Comment: thanks but i run your given command and got this error:invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: that's because you should escape the braces...see my 2nd answer

Comment: @ghostdog74 Thanks for that response about escaping braces. I don't know if I ever would have worked that out by myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

One more way to resolve the problem:

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/\(^.*\)\(page-\)\(.*\)/\1apple-\3.html/' Files
```

Here the searching patterns are stored and retrieved using references (`\1`, `\2`, `\3`).

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```bash
sed 's/$/\.html/g' file.txt
```

Comment: sed 's/$/\.html/g' file.txt